# Ruby on rails - Is there a way of rendering a partial found inside a subfolder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to know if the code below is correct. I simply want to render a partial found inside a subfolder.

My view folder is like this : Views/Subs/showPartials/_showform1.html.erb

The code below is not working and is displaying the error message `<<ActionView::MissingTemplate in Subs#show >>`

CODE:

```
<%= render :partial => 'showPartials/showform1' %>
```

Many many thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Provide the full path to partial:-

<%= render :partial => 'Subs/showPartials/showform1' %>

Thanks.....

Comment: Note that a peer subdirectory may also be specified.  To pull the partial ../books/_header.erb in, use <%= render :partial => "/books/header" %>

Answer (score 0):

Provide full path is the key

Like:

`= render 'clients/index/home'`

`= render 'clients/index/clients'`

`= render 'clients/index/footer'`